# Prevent Alt Tab menu overflow

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation

When a lot of windows are open, the alt tab menu overflow. [image]They just overflow and then I have to use left and right arrow buttons to navigate, not possible with a mouse pointer.

Hence I would like to wrap the contents to the next line.

Edit 1:
Any other extension you would suggest which could get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents cannot be wrapped without changing how the task switcher works, i.e., by changing the source code.

Note that, with the mouse, you can scroll for changing the contents. A behavior where the contents could be changed by e.g. hovering over the left or the right side would be a welcome addition to accommodate users of a mouse without a scroll wheel.

Comment: sad to know that